# Is google analytics count subdomain visitor in main domain

Tags: google-analytics

If i create some subdomain and visitor visit those subdomain is google analytic count them total as for my main domain viositor ?

As like i have `a.xxx.com` and `10` visitor visit it.
another `b.xxx.com` and `1000` visitor visit it.
other side `500` visiter visit `xxx.com`

i have/set google analytic tracking code for `xxx.com`

is that google analytic view `10+1000+500 = 1510` visitors in my google analytic dashboard ?
Is google analytics count all those subdomain visitor and add them as main domain visitor ?

Answer (score 0):

Tracking is not per hostname, it's per account id. If you use the same account id for multiple domains and subdomains you will get aggregated numbers for all domains and subdomains that use that id. To get number per domain you would have to create either different views with filters, or a segment or set the hostname as second dimension.